# How can requirejs provide a new "class" instance for each define with properties based on the filename?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, publish-subscribe, mediator

Use case is implementing a mediator pattern where each instance is a postal.js channel.

Explaining it with the actual code would require some postal.js knowledge, so my example below is conceptually similar, but only uses requirejs.

```
// animalSounds.js
define([],function(){
  return {
    cat:'meow',
    dog:'woof'
  };
});

// animalFactory.js ... the requirejs plugin
define(['animalSounds'],function(animalSounds){
  function animalClass(name){
    this.sound = animalSounds[name];
  }
  return {
    load:function(name, req, onload, config){
      onload(new animalClass(name)); 
    }
  }
});

// cat.js
define(['animalFactory'],function(animalInstance){
  animalInstance.sound === 'meow'; // should be true
});

// dog.js
define(['animalFactory'],function(animalInstance){
  animalInstance.sound === 'woof'; // should be true
});
```

Basically it's a factory that returns a new instance whenever it's required.  That part I can create fine.  What I'm struggling with is getting dynamic properties from other sources based on what module is requiring it.  While I could define the key as a string in each file, I'm hoping to use the filename as a key to stay DRY.

Comment: Adam, I've rolled back your edit. SO editorial practices are that answers should  not appear in questions. (If you have seen it on other questions, well their authors were incorrectly going against SO practices. Unfortunately, we can't catch every cases.) If you want to post an answer to your question, you should submit it as a formal answer, below the question.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for communicating in addition to changing it.  I would have submitted as a comment on your answer if comments allowed formatting.  Not important though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just minimally break the DRY principle and have `cat`, for instance, like this:

```
define(['animalFactory!cat'],function(animalInstance){
  animalInstance.sound === 'meow'; // should be true
});
```

The fact of the matter is while it would be *possible* to do what you want using a loader, the resulting code would be complicated, and would obscure the logic of your application. For instance, requiring `animalFactory` multiple times and expecting different results (which is what you have in your question) goes against one of the fundamental principles of RequireJS: requiring the same module name over and over again should return the same value over and over again.

Note that it is possible to require the `module` module (it is a special module) and then use `module.id` to know the name of the module you are in but unfortunately, this is not available for building the dependency list on your `define`.

Comment: Thanks Louis.  module.id did the trick.  I'm using require normally for the app files. Extensions to the core get their own sandboxed communication channel via the window.sandbox(fn) that returns a new sandbox via define(['module','sandbox']) internally.  Hiding the require use when instantiating sandboxes is even better than a plugin.  Fantastic!